# Disappearing shop in wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

After installing the Yoast SEO plugin and caching plugin my woocommerce shop on Wordpress website disappeared. I uninstalled these plugins cleared the cache. The problem is still there. I put the status of the woocommerce plugin here. Maybe a trained eye of one of you will find something that blocks the display of the store. The store should be displayed after clicking the shop element from navbar. Products are also not displayed in the categories submenu.

Website link: jewelsandbeauty.co.uk

```
### WordPress Environment ###

WordPress address (URL): https://jewelsandbeauty.co.uk
Site address (URL): https://jewelsandbeauty.co.uk
WC Version: 4.8.0
REST API Version: ✔ 4.8.0
WC Blocks Version: ✔ 3.8.1
Action Scheduler Version: ✔ 3.1.6
WC Admin Version: ✔ 1.7.3
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 5.6
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 256 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
WP Cron: ✔
Language: en_US
External object cache: –

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: LiteSpeed
PHP Version: 7.2.34
PHP Post Max Size: 64 MB
PHP Time Limit: 60
PHP Max Input Vars: 5000
cURL Version: 7.71.0
OpenSSL/1.1.1d

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.5.5-10.4.15-MariaDB
Max Upload Size: 64 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

### Database ###

WC Database Version: 4.8.0
WC Database Prefix: wp_
Total Database Size: 26.01MB
Database Data Size: 23.20MB
Database Index Size: 2.81MB
wp_woocommerce_sessions: Data: 0.36MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_api_keys: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_order_items: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rates: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_log: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_actions: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.11MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_claims: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_groups: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_logs: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_cartflows_ca_cart_abandonment: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_cartflows_ca_email_history: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_cartflows_ca_email_templates: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_cartflows_ca_email_templates_meta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_commentmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_comments: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_links: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_nextend2_image_storage: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_nextend2_section_storage: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_nextend2_smartslider3_generators: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_nextend2_smartslider3_sliders: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_nextend2_smartslider3_sliders_xref: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_nextend2_smartslider3_slides: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.11MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_options: Data: 4.47MB + Index: 0.11MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_postmeta: Data: 13.50MB + Index: 0.45MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_posts: Data: 2.09MB + Index: 0.22MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_smush_dir_images: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_termmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_terms: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_term_relationships: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_term_taxonomy: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_tm_taskmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_tm_tasks: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_usermeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_users: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_admin_notes: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_admin_note_actions: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_category_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_customer_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_download_log: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_coupon_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_product_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_stats: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_tax_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_product_meta_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_reserved_stock: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_tax_rate_classes: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_webhooks: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wpforms_tasks_meta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_indexable: Data: 1.52MB + Index: 0.22MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_indexable_hierarchy: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_migrations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_primary_term: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_prominent_words: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_seo_links: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB

### Post Type Counts ###

al_product: 1
attachment: 523
cartflows_flow: 1
cartflows_step: 2
custom_css: 6
elementor_library: 9
elementor-hf: 1
jet-woo-builder: 1
nav_menu_item: 46
oembed_cache: 5
page: 28
post: 1
product: 166
wpforms: 1

### Security ###

Secure connection (HTTPS): ✔
Hide errors from visitors: ✔

### Active Plugins (18) ###

Advanced Sidebar Menu: by OnPoint Plugins – 8.2.0
Akismet Anti-Spam: by Automattic – 4.1.7
Starter Templates: by Brainstorm Force – 2.3.9
Astra Widgets: by Brainstorm Force – 1.2.7
CartFlows: by CartFlows Inc – 1.5.22
Caxton: by PootlePress – 1.27.0
eCommerce Product Catalog for WordPress: by impleCode – 3.0.13
Elementor Pro: by Elementor.com – 3.0.2
Elementor: by Elementor.com – 3.0.14
Elementor - Header, Footer & Blocks: by Brainstorm Force
Nikhil Chavan – 1.5.4

Sidebar Manager: by Brainstorm Force – 1.1.6
WooCommerce Cart Abandonment Recovery: by CartFlows Inc – 1.2.8
List Products By Category Widget For WooCommerce: by Blaze Concepts – 1.3.0
Woo Title Limit: by Dima W. – 2.0.1
WooCommerce: by Automattic – 4.8.0
WooLentor Pro: by HasThemes – 1.5.6
WooLentor - WooCommerce Elementor Addons + Builder: by HasThemes – 1.7.6
WPForms Lite: by WPForms – 1.6.3.1

### Inactive Plugins (9) ###

Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights: by MonsterInsights – 7.14.0
Health Check & Troubleshooting: by The WordPress.org community – 1.4.5
Hello Dolly: by Matt Mullenweg – 1.7.2
JetWooBuilder For Elementor: by Crocoblock – 1.7.3
JetWoo Widgets For Elementor: by Crocoblock – 1.1.2 – Installed version not tested with active version of WooCommerce 4.0
Smush Pro: by WPMU DEV – 3.8.2
Stripe For WooCommerce: by Payment Plugins
support@paymentplugins.com – 3.2.9

WooBuilder blocks: by PootlePress – 3.6.0
WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway: by WooCommerce – 2.1.1

### Dropin Plugins (1) ###

advanced-cache.php: advanced-cache.php

### Settings ###

API Enabled: –
Force SSL: –
Currency: GBP (£)
Currency Position: left
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 2
Taxonomies: Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

Taxonomies: Product Visibility: exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog)
exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search)
featured (featured)
outofstock (outofstock)
rated-1 (rated-1)
rated-2 (rated-2)
rated-3 (rated-3)
rated-4 (rated-4)
rated-5 (rated-5)

Connected to WooCommerce.com: –

### WC Pages ###

Shop base: #4235 - /shop-new/
Cart: #97 - /cart/
Checkout: #98 - /checkout/
My account: #99 - /my-account/
Terms and conditions: #5199 - /privacy-policy/

### Theme ###

Name: Astra
Version: 2.6.2
Author URL: https://wpastra.com/about/
Child Theme: ❌ – If you are modifying WooCommerce on a parent theme that you did not build personally we recommend using a child theme. See: How to create a child theme
WooCommerce Support: ✔

### Templates ###

Overrides: –

### Action Scheduler ###

Complete: 38
Oldest: 2020-12-13 20:36:27 +0000
Newest: 2020-12-16 15:43:51 +0000

Pending: 1
Oldest: 2020-12-17 00:00:00 +0000
Newest: 2020-12-17 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: You need to select your Shop page in Woocommerce settings. Example screenshot: https://tielabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/WooCommerce-Settings-%E2%80%B9-TieLabs-%E2%80%94-WordPress.png

Comment: @Ozgur Sar The store has already been selected in the settings.

Comment: I’m sorry it was already present in the status log. Can you try to increase wordpress memory from wp-config.php?

Comment: @Ozgur Sar Memory increased to 256M. Still nothing changed. My dashboard is a bit different from yours. [link](https://imgur.com/1PVYzPH)

Comment: You can try to save permalinks. It will reset your .htaccess file. You can also try to use a different theme to check if it is a theme based issue.